# Fourier Transform of a Temperate Distribution

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f$ be a temperate distribution. Suppose that $f$ is a solution to the equation

$ f'-f= \delta_0 +1 $.

I want to find $ \hat{f}$...

Here's what I did:

Since $ f'-f= \delta_0 +1 $, then $ \hat{f'}-\hat{f}= \hat{\delta_0} +\hat{1} $.

So, we have $ \hat{f'}(\xi)-\hat{f}(\xi)= \hat{\delta_0}(\xi) +\hat{1}(\xi) $,

i.e., $  \xi \hat{f } (\xi)-\hat{f}(\xi)= 1 +\delta_0(\xi) $,

i.e., $   \hat{f } (\xi) = \dfrac{1 +\delta_0(\xi) }{ \xi -1}$.

Is this correct? and what happens when $ \xi=1$?

Moreover, how can I show that the solution to the above equation in the space of temperate distribution is unique?

Thank you!

Comment: "Tempered distribution" is a standard term.  As far as I know, "temperate distribution" is not.  A tempered distribution is a distribution that doesn't grow too fast.  Tempered distributions have Fourier transforms, and in fact the Fourier transform is a bijection from  the space of tempered distributions to itself. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy  In "Distributions and Operators", Gerd Grubb uses the term "temperate"; however, he states that it's the same as tempered :)

Answer (score 2):

(I would usually post this as a comment, but apparently I need an account for that.)

Suppose that $f \in \mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}) $ is a solution to the equation
$$
f'-f = \delta_0 + 1.
$$

Since you are following Gerd Grubb's textbook, have a look at the technique described on page 108, starting around equation (5.41). We can set the differential operator
$$P(D) = iD - 1 = \partial - 1,$$
noting that $D = \frac{1}{i}\partial$ (see page 424). Then the differential equation above can be written
$$P(D)f = \delta_0 + 1.$$
(Quick sanity check: $\delta_0+1$ is indeed in $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R})$, so we are OK to use this method.) Then applying Fourier transform (cf. (5.43)), we get
$$(i\xi-1)\hat{u}(\xi) = \mathscr{F}[\delta_0+1](\xi) \overset{(5.37),(5.38)}{=} 1 + 2\pi\delta_0(\xi),$$
i.e.,
$$\hat{u}(\xi) = \frac{1+2\pi\delta_0(\xi)}{i\xi-1}.$$
This is well-defined in $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R})$, since the denominator cannot be zero when $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. I think this is essential.

For uniqueness, I believe it suffices to use the fact that the Fourier transform $\mathscr{F}$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ onto itself (this is Theorem 5.17 in Grubb's book). Then the argument goes as follows: Suppose that $g \in \mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ is another solution to the above equation. Then $\hat{g}=\hat{f}$ by the above computation we have just done, so we find that $g = \mathscr{F}^{-1}[\hat{g}] = \mathscr{F}^{-1}[\hat{f}] = f$. Hence $f$ is a unique solution in $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R})$.

Good luck tomorrow, right? :-)